# Google Trends - Coronavirus

Tags: correlation, sample-size

I played around with Google Trends and Corona because I was interested when people started to search for it.

https://trends.google.de/trends/explore?date=2019-11-20%202020-01-09&geo=CN&q=Coronavirus,%2Fm%2F01cpyy,%2Fm%2F01f01y,%2Fm%2F02y_4q2,%2Fm%2F0g9pc

I tried to control for the beer and general virus.

[image]

It looks like peopled googles very early for the virus or am I missing something ?
Sample-size, other variables ?

Comment: I predict the results 2wks ahead with 99% certainty any interest?

Answer (score 9):

Coronaviruses are a group of viruses. According to the Wiki, coronaviruses were discovered in the 1960s. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronavirus

So people could have searched for "coronavirus" long before the current outbreak. Case in point, Google trends for year 2018:

[image]

And here for reference Google Ngram, indeed showing the term first appeared in the 1960s:

[image]